# Any protected firewall available

Tags: firewall, password-protection, protected-apps

is there any protected firewall available? I have tried many & the problem was as follow:
- it works very well but ANY user can simply uninstall it!! how didn't they put this into consideration.
- i used a program to hide it, and when I hide it it becomes disabled.

I used AFwall+ (root), Netguard..

Answer (score 1):

Try making them device administrators. I know that AFwall+ can be set as device admistrator. I have not used Netguard except for testing purposes in the last year but I believe it is also possible to set it as device admistrator.

Comment: Thank you, but AFwall+ not either any other firewall can be put as a device administrator.

Comment: I don't understand the comment. Are you unable to set AFwall+ as device administrator?

Comment: it seems there is one version of AFwall where you can activate it in device administrator..
Thank you all, I will get it .

Comment: If and only if the answer is satisfactory, you can mark it as accepted. See how to do it [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/tour).